# Ajustar Tabla HTML Automaticamente

Tags: html, html-tabla

Quisiera saber como hacer que una tabla de formato html cuando se agregue informacion se ajuste automaticamente osea se ajuste a las celdas.
Este es el codigo que estoy haciendo:

```html
<table align="center" border="1" style="width:auto; height:20px;" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr align="center" class="active">
    <td width="80">CÓDIGO</td>
    <td width="80">NOMBRE</td>
    <td width="150">APELLIDOS</td>
    <td width="80">DNI</td>
    <td width="250">FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</td>
    <td width="80">EDAD</td>
    <td width="80">SEXO</td>
    <td width="150">DIRECCIÓN</td>
    <td width="150">CORREO</td>
    <td width="80">TELÉFONO</td>
    <td width="80">ESPECIALIDAD</td>
    <td width="50">HORA(DESDE)</td>
    <td width="50">HORA(HASTA)</td>
    <td width="250">FECHA DE REGISTRO</td>
    <td>ACCIONES</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Ricardo</td>
    <td>Torres Torres</td>
    <td>12345678</td>
    <td>1980-02-12</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Masculino</td>
    <td>Av. Los Alisos</td>
    <td>ricardo@hotmail.com</td>
    <td>5213652</td>
    <td>Cardiologia</td>
    <td>06:00</td>
    <td>14:00</td>
    <td>2016-02-18</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Te refiera al titulo de cada casilla, no?

Comment: claro pero ademas cada informacion que se agregue a cada celda se ajuste automaticamente @AnimationsNow

Comment: Yo en tu caso, en vez de usar `text-align: center` usaría `white-space: nowrap` en los títulos de cada celda.

Comment: La imagen de la tabla que has puesto abajo, imagino que es el resultado que pretendes conseguir, ¿no?

Comment: El contenido ya se ajusta a las celdas por lo que no está claro a que se refiere la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

En el código que has mandado, tienes clases sin definir en el css aquí:

```
<table align="center" border="1" style="width:auto; height:20px;" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
```

Esas clases que tienes añadidas al elemento no producen ningún efecto si no las mencionas en el CSS.

También tienes mal esto en todos sus casos:

```
<td width="80">ESPECIALIDAD</td>
```

Esto no tiene ningún efecto sobre la tabla.

Aquí te he hecho un sencillo ejemplo de lo que más o menos creo que pretendes hacer:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <style>
            table {
                border: none;
                width: 100%;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            td { 
                padding: 5px 10px;
                text-align: center;
                border: 1px solid #999;
            }

            tr:nth-child(1) {
                background: #dedede;
            }
        </style>

<body>

    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>CÓDIGO</td>
                <td>NOMBRE</td>
                <td>APELLIDOS</td>
                <td>DNI</td>
                <td>FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</td>
                <td>EDAD</td>
                <td>SEXO</td>
                <td>DIRECCIÓN</td>
                <td>CORREO</td>
                <td>TELÉFONO</td>
                <td>ESPECIALIDAD</td>
                <td>HORA(DESDE)</td>
                <td>HORA(HASTA)</td>
                <td>FECHA DE REGISTRO</td>
                <td>ACCIONES</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Ricardo</td>
                <td>Torres</td>
                <td>12345678</td>
                <td>1980-02-12</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Masculino</td>
                  <td>Av. Los Alisos</td>
                <td>ricardo@hotmail.com</td>
                <td>5213652</td>
                <td>Cardiologia</td>
                <td>06:00</td>
                <td>14:00</td>
                <td>2016-02-18</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

De este modo, tienes un ligero margen añadido a las celdas para que el texto no se pegue a los bordes, añadas el texto que añadas, la celda se adaptará a éste.

Dentro del tag `<style>`, podrás ver `tr:nth-child(1) { background: #dedede; }`, esto es simplemente para agregar un estilo diferente solamente a la primera fila.

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.